# How to check server status in suse linux?

Tags: linux, server, suse

I have a below machine :

```
LSB Version:    core-2.0-noarch:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-noarch:core-2.0-x86_64:core-3.2-x86_64:core-4.0-x86_64:desktop-4.0-amd64:desktop-4.0-noarch:graphics-2.0-amd64:graphics-2.0-noarch:graphics-3.2-amd64:graphics-3.2-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: SUSE LINUX
Description:    SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
Release:        11
```

I have a server called as Xserver i need to check the status of server whether it is up/down/running.
What command should i use to check server status?

Answer (score 1):

Is your 'Xserver' a some kind of Linux daemon or service?
If so you should be able to check it with the following command:

```
systemctl status xserver
```

You need to be sure that your service name is 'xserver' exactly!
You can find which services are running on your system by using this command:

```
chkconfig --list
```